# Antisymmetry of the stochastic order

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, order-theory, probability-distributions

An *ordered topological space* is a topological space $X$ equipped with a partial order $\leq$ which is closed as a subset of $X\times X$. By antisymmetry of $\leq$, it follows that the diagonal of $X$ is closed as well, so that $X$ is necessarily Hausdorff.

The [*stochastic order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering) on the set of Radon probability measures on $X$ is given as follows. One defines $p\leq q$ if and only if $p(C) \leq q(C)$ for every closed upper set $C$.

> What is known about the antisymmetry of the stochastic order? Is it always antisymmetric? In other words, does $p(C) = q(C)$ for all closed upper sets $C$ imply $p = q$?

Here's what I know: [Edwards (1978)](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1978__28_4_53_0) has proven antisymmetry for compact $X$ (p.59). [Hiai, Lawson and Lim (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04187) have established it when $X$ is a certain type of cone in a Banach space (Theorem 4.3), using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem. Which other results are there along these lines?

Comment: Upper sets form a $\pi$-system, so I guess it will boil down to whether the upper sets generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: right, showing that the upper sets generate the $\sigma$-algebra is the approach taken in the second paper that I've linked to (see Proposition 4.1 in there). It's not clear whether this always holds though. Are you suggesting that it is also a *necessary* condition for the antisymmetry to hold?

Comment: I think it is "almost necessary", in that the distinction between a generating class and a determining class is often small (things like null sets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to answer this question in the positive [for all ordered topological spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06771).

The proof is completely elementary and unexpectedly simple.